# Use a glob to target any nested folders with a certain prefix

Tags: angular, angular-cli, glob

I have a project that has mock json data scattered across different modules. I'm trying to get all the json data to appear in the build using the angular.json config file.

Example list of paths I'm trying to target:

```
/app/app-mock-data/**
/feature-module/feature-module-mock-data/** 
/pages/page-module/page-module-mock-data/**
/other/other-module/other-module-mock-data/**
/nested/nested-module/further-nested-module/futher-nested-module-mock-data/**
```

Right now I'm just getting the assets file per module in this project with the angular.json.

```
// --configuration=mock
{
  "assets": [
    "src/assets",
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/favicon.png",
    {
      "glob": "**/* ",
      "input": "src/app/app-mock-data",
      "output": "/mock-assets/app-mock-data"
    },
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "src/app/feature-module/feature-module-mock-data",
      "output": "/mock-assets/feature-module-mock-data"
    },
    {
      "glob": "**/* ",
      "input": "src/app/pages/page-module/page-module-mock-data",
      "output": "/mock-assets/page-module-mock-data"
    },
    {
      "glob": "**/* ",
      "input": "src/app/other/other-module/other-module-mock-data",
      "output": "/mock-assets/other-module-mock-data"
    },
    {
      "glob": "**/* ",
      "input": "src/app/nested/nested-module/further-nested-module/futher-nested-module-mock-data",
      "output": "/mock-assets/futher-nested-module-mock-data"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any glob pattern that allows me to recursively get all items in folders with `*-mock-data` as a folder prefix?

```
// hopefully something like this..
"assets": [
  "src/assets",
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/favicon.png",
  {
    "glob": "*-mock-data/**/*",
    "input": "src/app/**/*",
    "output": "/mock-assets"
  }
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern

```
**/*-mock-data/**
```

You can test it using [globster.xyz](https://globster.xyz/?q=**%2F*-mock-data%2F**&f=%2Fapp%2Fapp-mock-data%2Ffile.js%2C%2Ffeature-module%2Ffeature-module-mock-data-wont-match%2Ffile.js%2C%2Fpages%2Fpage-module%2Fpage-module-mock-data%2Ffile.js%2C%2Fother%2Fother-module%2Fother-module-mock-data%2Ffile.js%2C%2Fnested%2Fnested-module%2Ffurther-nested-module%2Ffuther-nested-module-mock-data%2Ffile.js)